# angular 2.0.0-rc.1 how to configure a router to behave like UI-Router did?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get an angular2 router setup to support deep linking.  We used to use ui-router in angular 1.5 and it kept the state information to the right of a '#'.  I'm trying to understand if an Angular2 router either @angular/router or @angular/router-deprecated can be configured in a way to support this behavior. I'm finding some documentation that refers to HashLocationStrategy, but I can't import that from @angular/router-deprecated or @angular/router so I'm not sure these examples are still valid.

[Deep Linking Angular2 walk through](https://auth0.com/blog/2016/01/25/angular-2-series-part-4-component-router-in-depth/)

Specifically I can't do this import:

```
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategry} from 'angular2/router';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import it from '@angular/common':

main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap }         from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS }  from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { provide }           from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy,
    HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent }      from './app.component';


bootstrap(AppComponent, [
ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
provide(LocationStrategy,
     {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Reference: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router-deprecated.html